# Pattern for interruptible loops using actors

Tags: scala, actor, akka

I'm designing an actor that consumes items from an endless stream, and need a way to control when it starts and stops using messages.  Is there a common pattern for implementing interruptible loops like this with actors?  I was thinking of just having my actor send messages to itself.  Something like (pseudo Scala):

```
class Interruptible extends Actor {
  val stream: Stream
  val running: boolean

  def receive = {
    case "start" => {
      running = true
      consumeItem
    }

    case "stop" => {
      running = false
    }

    case "consumeNext" => consumeItem
  }

  def consumeItem {
    if (running) {
      stream.getItem
      this ! "consumeNext"
    }
  }
}
```

Is this the best way to go about things?

Thanks!

Comment: According to our latest figures Akka does about 3 million messages per second on an 8core machine. Are you sure you aren't prematurely optimizing here?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Viktor.  I rephrased the question to be about design.  Just trying to come to grips with the actor model!  Akka is great, BTW. -D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Perhaps encoded like this:

```
class Interruptible extends Actor {
  val stream: Stream

  def inactive: Receive = { // This is the behavior when inactive
    case "start" =>
      self become active
  }

  def active: Receive = { // This is the behavior when it's active
    case "stop" =>
      self become inactive
    case "next" =>
      doSomethingWith(stream.getItem)
      self ! "next"
  }

  def receive = inactive // Start out as inactive
}
```

Cheers,

Comment: Looks great, but how "self become active" might be implemented to preserve the elegance? Couldn't find method `become` in akka coming with scala 2.10. Or is it a pseudocode?

Comment: It moved to "context" with Akka 2.0. http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.2/scala/actors.html#Become_Unbecome